# Как правильно выводить файлы книги на сайте для создания онлайн-читалки?

Tags: php, txt, fb2, reader

Есть сайт на ucoz - легальная онлайн-библиотека. Правообладатели дают доступ к файлам на своем сервере в самых популярных текстовых форматах: epub, fb2, txt, pdf, docx и тд. В данный момент функционал сайта ограничен тем, что я даю моим пользователям возможность скачивать эти файлы. Но хотелось бы добавить к этому еще и возможность онлайн-чтения. Но проблема в том, что я очень далек от php (а он единственный из языков разрешен на ucoz, не считая js). Поэтому нужна помощь знающих людей о принципах, по которым это вообще можно реализовать.

Я пока это вижу примерно так: открывать файл нужного формата по прямой ссылке (к примеру, txt),  брать кусок текста, выводить его на странице, а также генерировать страницы пагинации, чтобы пользователь, кликая по ним, получал остальные куски файла.

Конечно, можно выводить весь файл целиком, но тогда кажется, будто бы это создаст слишком большую нагрузку на сайт.

Собственно, на фоне этого ряд вопросов:

1. Нет ли готовых сервисов/библиотек, которые помогли бы избежать мучений с разработкой?
2. Если их нет, то насколько адекватна моя идея?
3. Если файл делить на страницы пагинации, то как лучше это делать? Записать весь текст файла в массив, а потом поочередно оттуда дергать при переключении страницы? Или есть другой, более адекватный способ?)

Comment: Чтобы снизить нагрузку, надо разбить на страницы заранее. Дальше задача совершенно тривиальная, решается даже яваскриптом.